# How to handle this exception 'ascii' codec can't decode?

Tags: python, string, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

I get `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 620: ordinal not in range(128)`
again in my log files from appengine and I don't know what to do about it. The offending code appears to be `'name': form.name.data.decode('utf-8')` where I already tried everything to make it work, encode, decode and unicode() without knowing why it's not builtin. I usually get the answer here that I must know what the input is but why? And when I try with some foreign chars like åäö it does work so it's not obvious what the problem is. The full stacktrace is

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 620: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015p.373396352072543150/authhandlers.py", line 34, in dispatch
    webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015p.373396352072543150/main.py", line 2610, in post
    'name': form.name.data.decode('utf-8')
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015p.373396352072543150/authhandlers.py", line 104, in render
    self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(template_name, **values))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2_extras/jinja2.py", line 158, in render_template
    return self.environment.get_template(_filename).render(**context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "templates/2.html", line 1680, in top-level template code
    <div class="table_data"> {{form.text(cols="45", rows="10", placeholder=_('Please describe the product or service in a few simple sentences'))|safe}}{% if form.text.errors %} <div class="maintext">
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015p.373396352072543150/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 139, in __call__
    return self.widget(self, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015p.373396352072543150/main.py", line 2034, in __call__
    return super(MyTextArea, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015p.373396352072543150/wtforms/widgets/core.py", line 221, in __call__
    return HTMLString('<textarea %s>%s</textarea>' % (html_params(name=field.name, **kwargs), escape(text_type(field._value()))))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015p.373396352072543150/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 496, in _value
    return text_type(self.data) if self.data is not None else ''
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 620: ordinal not in range(128)
```

### Update 140209 06:02 CET

I also get the error using `decode`

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015r.373623653798528527/authhandlers.py", line 34, in dispatch
    webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015r.373623653798528527/main.py", line 2664, in post
    'name': form.name.data.encode('utf-8')
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015r.373623653798528527/authhandlers.py", line 104, in render
    self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(template_name, **values))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2_extras/jinja2.py", line 158, in render_template
    return self.environment.get_template(_filename).render(**context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "templates/2.html", line 223, in top-level template code
    {{ form.phonenumber(size="17", maxlength="14")|safe }}<label for="phone_hidden">{{ form.phoneview|safe }}{% trans %}View on site{% endtrans %}</label><br />{% trans %}Use areacode{% endtrans %}<br>
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015r.373623653798528527/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 139, in __call__
    return self.widget(self, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015r.373623653798528527/wtforms/widgets/core.py", line 123, in __call__
    kwargs['value'] = field._value()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2015r.373623653798528527/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 496, in _value
    return text_type(self.data) if self.data is not None else ''
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: `form.name.data` is most likely already Unicode, in which case `decode` would attempt to first encode it in ASCII and then decode the ASCII as UTF-8.

Comment: I think this article by Nick Johnson is really worth reading - http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `encode` rather than `decode`. What you have in `name.data` is a unicode string (you can understand that from the byte `0xe2` in error message) and you need to transform that into bytes string.

I've done some ipython fiddling:

```
In [32]: unichr(0xe2)
Out[32]: u'\xe2'

In [33]: unichr(0xe2).encode("utf-8")
Out[33]: '\xc3\xa2'

In [34]: print unichr(0xe2).encode("utf-8")
â
```